# @XMLElementWrapper issue with codehaus JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, jackson

I am trying to get the correct JSON for

```
public class MyTestResponse {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElement(name = "values")
    public List<String> test = Arrays.asList("Sidney");
}
```

I now get

```
"data": [
  "Sidney"
],
```

instead of

```
"data":{
    "values": [
        "Sidney"
    ]
},
```

I am using org.codehaus.jackson stack (1.9.0) inside ServiceMix 7 M3.

My JSON provider extends org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;


public class MyJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {
        super();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(secondary, primary);
        mapper.getDeserializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
        this.setMapper(mapper);
    }

}
```

How can I tell the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider not to replace the XmlElement name but tow wrap it?

Comment: You can either wrap it inside data or inside values. Both are not supported

Comment: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider for example does render values inside a data element. We used that implementation first, but it has an issue in that it does not serialize an array with a single element correct. That is why we switched but then ran into this issue. So I don't think your comment is right, right?

Answer (score -1):

As you have discovered JSON marshalling doesn’t honor JAXB annotations.  Enable the following MapperFeature on your jackson ObjectMapper (your instance named mapper)

```
mapper.enable(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME);
```

Comment: According to the spec, the default setting should be good, and it is. But this is fasterxml and we are using codehaus impl. I could use fasterxml impl but that has the issue of not properly serializing an array with a single element. If that can be solved this is OK for me too.

Comment: see my related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959368/xmlelementwrapper-issue-with-com-fasterxml-jackson-jacksonjaxbjsonprovider

Comment: Sorry I did overlook the implementation you are using.  Faster XML does have a serialization feature for whether you unwrap a single element array.  WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED (default: false)
Feature to change handling of single-element Arrays, java.util.Collections, so that such arrays/collections are serialized as "unwrapped" elements, not as JSON Arrays.  Have you tried it and still encounter issues?  Your link seems to be pointing to the same post.

Comment: The other link does point to another question, handling about fasterxml and I tried to add the WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, without success.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the Serializer to write single element array wrapped { "arrayProperty" : [ 1 ] }  or unwrapped, following the "BadgerFish" convention, { "arrayProperty" : 1 }.  In the other post you are enabling both so I am assuming the later.

Comment: I want to have { "arrayProperty" : [ 1 ] } . I assume I am doing something wrong then in the other post

Comment: I believe so.  When WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED is  enabled, a POJO with array that normally looks like this:

  { "arrayProperty" : [ 1 ] }
will instead be serialized as
  { "arrayProperty" : 1 } .  You should disable it.  You can either use the disable() method and pass the feature or configure it to true or false.  You should also change ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY to to disabled as well.  These two should stay in sync.

Comment: Lets move this discussion to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959368/xmlelementwrapper-issue-with-com-fasterxml-jackson-jacksonjaxbjsonprovider