# @XMLElementWrapper issue with com.fasterxml.jackson JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to get the correct JSON for

```
public class MyTestResponse {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElement(name = "values")
    public List<String> test = Arrays.asList("Sidney");
}
```

I now get

```
"values": [
    "Sidney"
],
```

instead of

```
"data":{
    "values": [
        "Sidney"
    ]
},
```

So the wrapper element "data" is not present.

I am using com.fasterxml.jackson stack (2.8.6) inside ServiceMix 7 M3.

My JSON provider extends com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;

@Provider
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json" })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json" })
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {

        super();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
        AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        AnnotationIntrospector pair = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(primary, secondary);

        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        this.setMapper(mapper);

    }

}
```

How can I tell the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider to render the wrapper element around the values element?

Comment: @m-rizzo changing the WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED feature does not seem to have any effect at all.