# CXF JSONProvider marshalling causes unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: json, unit-testing, jaxb, cxf, marshalling

I am trying to write a test on org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.
I merely need to show the JSON representation of a given class.
I know there are other JSONProviders such as Jackson, but for this test it needs to be the one from cxf.

If I run the following test

```
package be.axi.jackson;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.MetadataMap;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;



public class JacksonTest {

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Simple", namespace = "be.axi.test")
    static class Simple {

    @XmlElement(name = "values")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    protected List<String> _list;

    public List<String> getList() {
        return _list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> l) {
        _list = l;
    }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCxf() throws IOException {
    JSONProvider<Object> jsonProvider = new JSONProvider<Object>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("foo");
    l.add("bar");
    Simple s = new Simple();
    s.setList(l);

    jsonProvider.writeTo(l, Simple.class, Simple.class.getAnnotations(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, null, bos);
    String expected = "{\"data\":{\"values\":[\"foo\"]}}";
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, bos.toString());
    }



}
```

I get

```
feb 02, 2017 9:47:19 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider handleJAXBException
WARNING: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

How can I fix this?
I really only need to get the JSON representation of Simple.class from the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing the `List<String> l` instance  instead of `Simple`  to `jsonProvider.writeTo(l,`. Change to `s`

```
jsonProvider.writeTo(s, Simple.class, Simple.class.getAnnotations(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, null, bos);
```

To get the expected output add

```
jsonProvider.setDropRootElement(true);
```

And change `@XmlElement` and `@XmlElementWrapper` of attribute to getter. This would be the code

```
package be.axi.jackson;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;



public class JettisonTest {

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Simple", namespace = "be.axi.test")
    static class Simple {
        protected List<String> _list;

        @XmlElement(name = "values")
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
        public List<String> getList() {
            return _list;
        }
        public void setList(List<String> l) {
            _list = l;
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testCxf() throws IOException {
        JSONProvider<Object> jsonProvider = new JSONProvider<Object>();
        jsonProvider.setDropRootElement(true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("foo");
        l.add("bar");
        Simple s = new Simple();
        s.setList(l);

        jsonProvider.writeTo(s, Simple.class, Simple.class.getAnnotations(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, null, bos);
        String res = bos.toString();
        String expected = "{\"data\":{\"values\":[\"foo\",\"bar\"]}}";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, res);
    }
}
```

Note that you are using the default JSON implementation of CXF, that is Jettison, not jackson

Comment: Thanks, I know it is Jettison, but I'm writing a test case for a bug in Jackson and am using Jettison to show the difference ;-) See to the issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959368/xmlelementwrapper-issue-with-com-fasterxml-jackson-jacksonjaxbjsonprovider which does not exist in the Jettison implementation.